# Azure VM setup with Extension from Powershell hangs

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm-role

I am provisioning an Azure VM using powershell script, and specify to inject a powershell extension. This behaviour worked ok last time on 1st June, but yesterday when I tried again, the VM in the Azure Management had a status of "Running (Installing Extensions)", and it didn't change after an hour at which point I gave up and deleted the deployment.

I have a very basic script for deploying the VM and also an empty powershell script that I inject (all this setup worked before):

```
$username = "VMUser1"
$password = "SomethingAsPa$$1"

$imagename = "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201404.01-en.us-127GB.vhd"
$name = "unqvmname"
$serviceName = "unqvmname"
$location = "North Europe"

$fileUrl1 = 'http://portalvhds3r84wq5g3925q.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/dummy.ps1'

$vm = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $name -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $imageName
$vm = Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -VM $vm -Windows -AdminUsername $username -Password $password

$vm = Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -VM $vm -FileUri $fileUrl1 -Run 'dummy.ps1' -Argument 'arg1_some_data'
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Location $location -VMs $vm
```

The $fileUrl1 is a empty powershell file.

Running this will end up in a VM that gets hanged in a "Running (Installing Extensions)" status. Does anyone else happen to have this problem and know a solution?

Comment: What will happen if execute second custom script execution on the second VM, Say -  "$vm = Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension -VM $vm -FileUri $fileUrl1 -Run 'dummy1.ps1' -Argument 'arg1_some_data'", will this work ? Not working for me now. if run with one script it is working fine

Comment: not sure I understand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today 6 June 2014, all came back to normal. The VMs are being created and the extension scripts run with success.

Comment: This happens sometimes. I believe MS keep on upgrading and modifying the extensions. Even I have faced the same issue. Sometimes the same code doesn't work